# Ising Model in Python not giving correct results

Tags: python, physics

I wrote some code for the ising model in python (2d). Everything looks seems to be calculating correctly except the number of good and bad steps. Good steps is defined as steps where the spin is changed because the change in energy (d_energy) is less than or equal to zero. A bad step is when the spin is changed because a random integer is less than the value of e^(-d_energy/(Kb * temp) where kb is boltzman's constant. And there is a no step where d_energy is greater than zero and rand is > than the e^(what i wrote above).

When i talked to a professor about this, he told me that when I make the temp really high, the number of bad steps should be half of the total number of steps

```
from numpy import zeros
from random import choice, random
import math

def create_lattice(nx,ny):
   possibleSpins = [-1,1]
   lattice = zeros((nx,ny))
   for i in range(nx):
     for j in range(ny):
        lattice[i,j] = choice(possibleSpins)
 return lattice

def ising_model(nsweeps, nx, ny, Js, kb, temp):

    s_energy = 0.0
    e_energy = 0.0
    d_energy = 0.0
    spin = 0.0
    rand = 0.0
    good = 0.0
    bad = 0.0
    nostep = 0.0
    lattice = create_lattice(nx, ny)
    energies = zeros((nx,ny))
    print(lattice)
    # Each sweep is a complete look at the lattice
    for sweeps in range(nsweeps):
        for i in range(nx):
            for j in range(ny):
                spin = lattice[i][j]
                s_energy = -1 * Js * spin * (lattice[(i-1)%nx][j] + lattice[i][(j-1)%ny] + lattice[i][(j+1)%ny] + lattice[(i+1)%nx][j])
                lattice[i][j] = -1 * spin
                e_energy = -1 * Js * lattice[i][j] * (lattice[(i-1)%nx][j] + lattice[i][(j-1)%ny] + lattice[i][(j+1)%ny] + lattice[(i+1)%nx][j])


                d_energy = e_energy - s_energy
                rand = random()
                if d_energy <= 0 :
                    good = good + 1
                elif d_energy > 0 and rand <= math.exp(-1 * d_energy / (kb * temp)):
                    bad = bad + 1
                else:
                    lattice[i][j] = spin
                    nostep = nostep + 1
                print(math.exp(-1 * d_energy / (kb * temp)))
                print(rand)


    print(lattice)
    print(good)
    print(bad)
    print(nostep)
    # energies array is
    return energies



ising_model(10,7,7,1.0,1.0,10000000000000000000000000000.0)
```

Comment: And what is it you are seeing?

Comment: Your integration doesn't separate sweeps: you change lattice in place, so some of your cells get flipped because of a change you've already made in that sweep.  That probably isn't what you intended, so I'd make a copy of lattice at the start of the `for sweeps` loop and change that instead.  [Note: this is just a programming suggestion, I have no idea what the "good step/bad step" ratio should be.]

Comment: @Barber I am seeing that the good sweeps are twice that of the bad. So the bad sweeps are 1/3 of the total number of steps.
@ DSM Thanks. for the suggestion. I'll try it out and think about it

Comment: The creation of your initial array can be simplified (and speed up) to `lattice = random.randint(-1,1,size=(N,N))*2+1`. What if your spins are not `[-1,1]`? Then you don't have an Ising model anymore (c.f. the  Potts model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potts_model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 6 possibilities for the delta in energy: -8, -4, 0, 0, 4, 8. I repeat 0 because there are two different configurations with that energy. The probability of each of those is 1/6 for a random configuration. That means 1/3 for d_energy > 0, 1/3 for d_energy < 0 and 1/3 for d_energy == 0.

If you change `if d_energy <= 0 :` to `if d_energy < 0 :` you will get a third "good" a third "bad" and a third "nostep". I think what your professor meant is that the number of "bad" steps should be the same as the number of "good" step for infinite temperature. Which is the case if you fix the '<='.

Edit: you may also want to have a >= for the elif.